# How can I add non-free network firmware to my Devuan install?

Tags: linux, debian, networking, devuan

I have a Dell PowerEdge T710 I'm trying to run as a home server. I have successfully installed Devuan, however I failed to set up the network properly. I'm wondering if there's any way to add the non-free network drivers for its `Broadcom Limited NetXtreme II BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet controller`. I'm also open to reinstalling, but if I'm gonna do that I'd like some guidance on adding the proper network firmware to the installation image. I'm also open to giving up and using the debian non free net install iso. (I'm using Devuan to play with other init systems eventually but its not super important that I stay with this distribution)

Comment: You might want to test antiX, it does a much better job of staying out of systemd and comes by default with more firmware installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As devuan is based on Debian, you add the Debian non-free repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch non-free
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ stretch/updates non-free
```

Then to install the corresponding firmware package for the BCM5709 Gigabit Ethernet

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install firmware-bnx2x
```

As for downloading manually, you review what any stretch package is for and download it from https://packages.debian.org/stretch/ ; in this case, https://packages.debian.org/stretch/firmware-bnx2x

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way I can obtain those packages from another machine as I do not have working network on the server at the moment. And do I need to replace stretch with ascii if I'm using the newer build?

Comment: I am afraid I am *not that* familiar with Devuan. I use antiX *and* Debian. I added to the answer a generic lead where you can download any packages you might need.